# jQuery .click function is not working in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I could be missing something, but I am not sure why my JQuery.click event is not working with the corresponding button.

HTML CODE: `<button id="jan7" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Let's Check!</button>`

JS/JQuery CODE:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("jan7").click(function(){
        alert("The button was clicked");
    });
});
</script>
```

On my HTML page, here is the order of the scripts I am calling (which is assume to be correct):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="countDown.js"></script>
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: `$("jan7")` should be `$("#jan7")`. In jQuery, IDs need a `#` prefixed to them. You should learn how to use the developer tools to troubleshoot and debug your code as the error would've lead you to the answer.

Comment: So it wasn't an ID typo thing. How is the `#jan7` element being created on the page? Is it in there when the page loads, or is it created later? If it is a dynamically created element, you need to look into event delegation.

Comment: @Snowmonkey I’m not sure exactly what you mean... the button (id) should be in there when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

The button is using Id =jan7

jquery need "#" when you are using selectors

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jan7").click(function(){
        alert("The button was clicked");
    });
});
</script>`
```

Comment: So even with the added “#”, I’m still not getting any response from my button when clicked.

Comment: Yeah, It definitely works in jsfiddle. I'm not exactly sure what is going on with it...maybe I am referencing my scripts wrong on the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

be sure if you have it as ID or as a Class.

In case it is a class you should use $('.jan7') or in case its an id $('#jan7')

The target element you want to click on could be something like this.

or

Comment: Don’t worry, I’m just an idiot. I had the function wrapped in the <script> tag for who knows what reason.... we’re all good now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Story of my life :D